# Add strings from help page into transifex (or use existing keys)

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help

As moderator, I can edit this page. But there are buttons with untranslated text:

1. Save Changes
2. Cancel

> [image]

Could you add these strings into transifex or use existing strings?